# How can I make my search give results based on strings from a multi-line column on a list?

Tags: list, search, search-results, multiline-text-field

I have created a list, and added a multi-line column to the list called "Description".  When I search I would like the search to provide results from what is in the "Description" column.  Currently my search results do not return anything related to what is in the "Description" column.  I tired to see if I could index the column, but that is not available to do.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately**, the `Multiple Lines of Text` column cannot be Indexed!

---

**Workaround**

Try to create a column with a `single line of text` and mention the main keywords that already exists in the `Multiple Lines of Text` column

---

**Unsupported Column Types for indexing**

- Multiple lines of text
- Choice (multi-valued)
- Calculated
- Hyperlink or Picture
- Custom Columns
- Person or Group (multi-valued) (Lookup)
- External data

**Supported Column Types for indexing**

- Single line of text
- Choice (single value)
- Number
- Currency
- Date and Time
- Person or Group (single value) (Lookup)
- Managed Metadata (Lookup)
- Yes/No
- Lookup (Lookup)

Comment: Thank you, this helps.  Is there a way to pull out keywords from a multi-line column to add to a single line column without manually going through and doing that for every entry on a list?

Comment: You can create a workflow/custom solution to loop for each item and update the newly created column, but in your case, the issue is How you let the custom solution to know which words should be the keywords!!